# How to handle a hundred thousand requests in REST web service?

Tags: java, rest, request

I am using REST framework in Java with restlet api for my webservice.
    If 100,000 users post requests for the web service, how do I handle this?
    Please anybody can suggest me the idea to handle 100,000 requests for REST webservice?

Comment: What approach have you tried so far?

Comment: the question is to vague and broad. Start researching on how to build scalable applications. You will encounter terms like scaling up (throwing more ram/cpus) or scaling horizontally (distributed systems). Then ask some specific questions. This might give you a start: http://www.quora.com/Amazon-Web-Services/What-is-a-good-initial-architecture-for-a-social-web-app-on-AWS-that-can-scale-over-time

Comment: Thank Your reply. I havnt tried any scalable tool yet. I am using a simple restlet api's in my webservice with MySQL database.

Comment: 100,000 requests per...second? day? year? lifetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your web-service on multiple server to avoid the performance hit.you can also use cloud computing (for example amazon micro instance.. its free) and load balancer   to balance the load on each server.

Comment: Just 1 ec2 micro instance is free for 1yr, which is far from being "scalable". You need more instanced if you are planning to get 100k hits to your web service

Comment: If the application is commercial then you can buy mini instance.

Comment: Just an advice. There is no magic bullet. You also need to write your code in a way which scales. ec2 gives you the infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is use a Load Balancer and reduce the load on a single server.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too generic to answer. There are many aspects to writing an application that scales well. Books like [Scalability rules](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321753887) help highlight the different areas you can work on. Databases / Application servers / Cache / State and some things to consider. No one can give you a specific answer for this question.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, I'll refer this book.